# Can orgmk scripts accept multiple arguments?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have a directory `~/foo/` containing lots of  `.org` files. These files are generated by a script and I want to export them to `.txt` files. I currently use [orgmk](https://github.com/fniessen/orgmk) (specifically `org2txt`) to do this. My script is

```
for file in ~/foo/*.org; do
    org2txt ${file}
done
```

The problem is that this is *slow*. The documentation for orgmk mentions something about orgmk scripts having the capability to export all org documents under a directory recursively but I can't seem to figure out the commands to do this. Does anyone know how to speed up my script?

Comment: I guess this is slow because emacs is started for each of the files to be exported. Perhaps there's a way in orgmk to start emacs one time and export all the files?  Otherwise it shouldn't be too difficult to script that *within* emacs.

Comment: @JeanPierre Figuring out how to get orgmk to start emacs one time and export all the files is exactly what I'd like to do!

Comment: Per [this thread](https://github.com/fniessen/orgmk/issues/4), it appears that what you are asking for is not supported with orgmk.

Comment: I agree, I reviewed the scripts and I noticed that the orgmk call a new emacs session each time, also it seems that it doesn't use the (with-temp-buffer) macros which would help to speed-up. Also it treats all txt files as org-files, that may be an issue for you too. A possible short term solution is to create a wrapper that will call orgmk for each file concurrently (orgmk f1 & orgmk f2& etc). Otherwise you could work with the implementer to enhance it but it requires quite a bit of effort

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's interested, the following bash script speeds up the process a bit.

```
#!/bin/bash

find $1 -type f -iname "*.org" -print0 | parallel -0 org2txt
```

Per @Joafigue's recommendation this script runs `orgmk` for each file concurrently. Consequently it requires [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Effectively, the script searches for all org files in the given path and runs the command

```
$ parallel org2txt ::: first.org second.org third.org ...
```

Obviously this is rather hackish, but I'm now significantly less bothered.

I'd still love to see orgmk gain the capability to process many files at once!